# What is fastest way to compute average of python array different elements with condition?

Tags: python, numpy

The `Python` code below executes in about `2 sec`. An equivalent code in `C` executes in `6 ms`.

Some explanations: I have serial data of 2 `ADC` channels (`adc0`, `adc1`, `adc0`, `adc1`, ...).
If `adc1 <= 10` I must add `adc1` to the sum, else I must add `adc0`. These values are multiplied by different coefficients (`0.1` and `0.01`).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import time
import numpy as np 

dd = np.random.randint(0, 20, size=(2*1000*1000))

t_start = time.clock()

avg_sum1 = 0.0
BlockOffset = 0     
while BlockOffset < len(dd):
    if dd[BlockOffset + 1] <= 10:
        avg_sum1 += dd[BlockOffset + 1] * 0.1
    else:
        avg_sum1 += dd[BlockOffset + 0] * 0.01
    BlockOffset += 2

print('Avg: ' + str(avg_sum1 / len(dd) / 2))    
print('Exe time: ' + str(time.clock() - t_start))
```

What is fastest way to do this with built-in functions or `numpy`?

Comment: Although the question may be on-topic here, [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) might be more suitable for your demonstrated needs.

Comment: Please add some written explanation of what your code needs to do, also expected output.

Comment: You should not time your code using [`time.clock()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.clock). Prefer using [`time.perf_counter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.perf_counter) or the [`timeit` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html)

Comment: Thank you Mathias.  But for me need increase computing speed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly you need to fix your average calc (operator precedence):

```
avg_sum1 / (len(dd) / 2)  # or avg_sum1 / len(dd) * 2

Out[]:
0.31740819000001924
2.8 s ± 28.2 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

You can do this in `numpy`, e.g.:

```
In []:
np.where(dd[1::2] <= 10, dd[1::2]*0.1, dd[0::2]*0.01).mean()

Out[]:
0.31740818999999987
10.8 ms ± 61.3 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: I tested both solution on my machine:  
    
f1  
Avg: 0.31760221000002087  
Exe time: 1.982864  
f2(AChampion)  
Avg: 0.3176022100000002  
Exe time: 0.017103  
f3(Ralf)  
{'sum': 317602.2100000002, 'avg': 0.3176022100000002, 'calc_time':   0.07925199999999988, 'n': 1000000}

Answer (score -1):

There are many ways to speed it up. Here is a solution using `pandas` (maybe that can also be done using just `numpy`).

In this code, `f1()` is your original function and `f2()` is using `pandas`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import time

def f1(data):
    t_start = time.perf_counter()

    offset = 0
    sum_1 = 0.0
    while offset < data.shape[0]:
        if data[offset + 1] <= 10:
            sum_1 += data[offset + 1] * 0.1
        else:
            sum_1 += data[offset + 0] * 0.01
        offset += 2
    n = data.shape[0] / 2
    avg_1 = sum_1 / n

    t_end = time.perf_counter()

    return {
        'calc_time': t_end - t_start,
        'n': n,
        'sum': sum_1,
        'avg': avg_1,
    }

def f2(data):
    t_start = time.perf_counter()

    df = pd.DataFrame()
    df['adc0'] = data[0::2]     # every second element, starting at 0
    df['adc1'] = data[1::2]     # every second element, starting at 1

    df['sum_value'] = np.where(
        df['adc1'] <= 10,
        df['adc1'] * 0.1,
        df['adc0'] * 0.01)
    sum_1 = df['sum_value'].sum()
    n = df.shape[0]
    avg_1 = sum_1 / n

    t_end = time.perf_counter()

    return {
        'calc_time': t_end - t_start,
        'n': n,
        'sum': sum_1,
        'avg': avg_1,
    }

if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = np.random.randint(0, 20, size=(2*1000*1000))

    r = f1(numbers)
    print(r)
    r = f2(numbers)
    print(r)
```

This code shows that `f2()` is faster, using about `123 ms` (less than 10% of the time of `f1()`).

```
# f1
{'avg': 0.31791369000003045, 'n': 1000000.0, 'sum': 317913.69000003044,
 'calc_time': 4.765112441743648}
# f2
{'avg': 0.31791368999999986, 'n': 1000000, 'sum': 317913.68999999989,
 'calc_time': 0.12356162259120662}
```

**Obs:** I assume that the difference of `sum` and `avg` between the two functions originates in how the float precision is handled, but I don't know for sure.
How many decimal places do you need to consider for your use case? Does this small difference matter?

Comment: Note: `0.1235...` is about `123ms` - `0.002` would be `2ms`.

Comment: Note:  input data for f1 and f2 same, but sum and avg difference. Why?

Comment: @AChampion your right, I mixed up my conversion. I corrected the time in my answer.

Comment: @Darius I added a note to my answer. In short: I am not sure where the difference comes from.